# When in a Polymer component's life cycle are changed watchers fired for declaratively-specified values?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

From the [Polymer docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods), the life cycle for most callbacks is clear:

```
 created -> ready -> attached -> domReady
    ^                               |
    |                               |
     ---------- detached <----------
```

And I imagine attributeChanged() will be fired at any point in this lifecycle when an attribute is modified, e.g. even as early as when created:

```
created: function() {
  this.attribute = 'newValue';
}
```

But what if an instance of my element is provided a value declaratively?

```
<my-element attribute="newValue"></my-element>
```

When in the element life cycle are attribute changed watchers fired in this case?

Comment: a simple test can determine your answer, but i would guess that a hard-coded value (unlike a dom-set value) is not technically changed until it's changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% I understand what you mean, but using a simple test it turns out that the `attributeChanged` event is called after `attached` and before `domReady`. The attribute value however is already readable from `ready` onwards. This is easy to understand, because the `attributeChanged` event is called from a javascript callback function and the same applies for the `domReady` event, however they don't trigger straight away as the code is already running.

If you set the value in the `created` event it will **not** in any way be reflected (except of course in the function itself where you assigned it). Attributes are handled *after* the `created` event, but *before* the `ready` event.

---

If you want to see this for yourself:

```
<my-element myAttribute="attributeValue"></my-element>
```

and the element itself is defined as

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="myAttribute">
  <template>
    <span>Hello from <b>my-element</b>. This is my Shadow DOM.</span>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      created: function() {
        //has no effect on the element:
        //this.myAttribute = "newValue";

        console.log("created", this.myAttribute);
      },          
      ready: function() {
        //works fine:
        //this.myAttribute = "newValue";

        console.log("ready", this.myAttribute);
      },
      attached: function() {
        console.log("attached", this.myAttribute);
      },
      domReady: function() {
        console.log("domReady", this.myAttribute);
      },
      myAttributeChanged: function() {
        console.log("myAttributeChanged", this.myAttribute);
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, David! I confirmed this with a runninng version on a service I just discovered (ele): https://ele.io/e/ZJIJZhYGgx